# Probability of winning die game

Tags: probability

Suppose we play a game where we roll a six-sided die. If a $4$, $5$, or $6$ is rolled, I get $1$ point. If a $1$, $2$, $3$ is rolled, you get $1$ point. We play first to $5$, but the winner must also win by $2$. If we are tied at $5$, what’s the probability that you win the game?

My approach has been that for "you" to win $2$ consecutive games, the probability is $\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$.

I'm not sure of it though. Is this approach correct?

Answer (score 3):

Well, sure one could take that approach, and consider all of the edge cases, and take large infinite sums over all of them, or one could make the following observation. (An observation that could make life a bit more easy is to realize that this dice game is equivalent to a coin flipping game, but even as so, the infinite sum still isn't so fun.)

The game is symmetrical for you and your opponent. Hence, your probability of winning is as good as your opponent's, i.e., you have a $\color{red}{50\%}$ of winning.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is wrong because it only accounts for the probability of winning the next 2 points, which as you have calculated is 0.25, but doesn't account for the possibility of winning the game later.

The answer by @Rushabh Mehta (which I upvoted) gives the correct answer of your winning the game of $p = 0.5$, based on a symmetry argument.

Here is a fairly simple way of getting the correct answer $p = 0.5$ using an approach which generalizes better to other problems than the symmetry argument.

The probability of your winning the game equals the probability of winning the game in the next 2 points plus {the probability that no ones wins the games in the next 2 points} times {the probability of your winning the game starting at 6 to 6 tie}.  But the probability of your winning the game starting at 6 to 6 tie is the same as p, which is the probability of your winning the game starting at 5 to 5 tie.

So $p = 0.25 + 0.5p$, whose solution is $p = 0.5$.